# I am bit confused on Complexity comparison between 2 binary tree, if identical, below is the code for the same

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search, algorithmic-trading

Binary tree identical or not with another binary tree code below gives linear complexity i.e big O (n) where n is number of node of the binary tree with least number of nodes.

```
 boolean identical(Node a, Node b)  
{ 
    if (a == null && b == null) 
        return true; 

    if (a != null && b != null)  
        return (a.data == b.data 
                && identical(a.left, b.left) 
                && identical(a.right, b.right)); 

    /* 3. one empty, one not -> false */
    return false; 
}
```

(Fibonacci series using recursion gives exponential complexity)
Complexity of below code is 2^n.

```
class Fibonacci  { 
    static int fib(int n) 
    { 
       if (n <= 1) 
         return n; 
       return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    } 
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    { 
       int n = 9; 
     }  
}
```

My question is both are looking similar but one has linear complexity and another has exponential. Could anyone clarify on both algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fibonacci Series**

If you build a tree for the recursive code to generate the fibonacci series, it will be like:

```
              fib(n)

      fib(n-1)      fib(n-2)

  fib(n-2) fib(n-3)   fib(n-3)  fib(n-4)
```

at what level you will encounter fib(1) so that the tree can "stop" ?

at `( n-1 )`th level you will encounter `fib(1)` and there the recursion stops.
  The number of nodes will be of order of `2^n` because there are `(n-1)` levels.

**Binary Tree Comparison**

Lets consider your binary tree comparison.

Lets assume both are complete binary trees. According to your algorithm it will visit all nodes once and if 'h' is the height 
  of the tree , the number of nodes will be order of `2^h`. You can say the complexity in that case as `O(2^h)`.

The `O(n)` in this case is equivalent to `O(2^h)`

Comment: Is it possible to accept either the other answer or this one?

Comment: So basically both have the same complexity that is number of node in a binary tree?

Comment: As I said `n` in the binary comparison is not equal to `n` in the fibonacci series, they are different. If you count number of nodes in fibonacci tree it is of the order 2^(n-1) where n is the number for which you are calculating fib(n). Whereas it is just `n` in binary tree comparison - number of nodes. BTW please do not post your thought as an answer. Consider deleting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference originates in a different definition of *n*. While the naive recursive algorithm for Fibonacci numbers also performs a kind of traversal in a graph, the value of *n* is not defined by the number of nodes in that graph, but by the input number.

The binary tree comparison however, has *n* defined as a number of nodes.

So *n* has a completely different meaning in these two algorithms, and it explains why the time complexity in terms of *n* comes out so differently.